# Use a Cocoapod from main project into a Swift package

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, podfile

I've developed a simple `Swift Package` with a `UIView` to use it in more projects.

I needed in that `UIView` to use a `UIImageView` that receives the image from a `URL` and I want for that to use `SDWebImage`.

I've added in my `Swift Package Package.swift` the `SDWebImage` as dependency and it created a `Package.resolved` in root directory and also added a `Package dependency` to `SDWebImage`:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPacket",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(name: "MyPacket", targets: ["MyPacket"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(name: "SDWebImage", url: "https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "5.0.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MyPacket",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "SDWebImage", package: "SDWebImage")]
           )
    ]
)
```

Everything works well until this point.

In my `main project` I also have `SDWebImage` as a `pod` installed and now in `main project` beside `MyPacket` in `Package Dependencies` it also shows `SDWebImage` as a dependency which means that `SDWebImage` is both in `Podfile` and `Package Dependencies`.

The application works but it throws this warning for every `SDWebImage method`:

```
objc[72670]: Class SDWeakProxy is implemented in both /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/81EA832E-6ED3-4560-8994-298CB8A00D2A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B01EFC62-3996-473D-9F8C-6FCCF80BF077/MyMaiProject.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage (0x10c5cd370) 
and /Users/use/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/81EA832E-6ED3-4560-8994-298CB8A00D2A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B01EFC62-3996-473D-9F8C-6FCCF80BF077/MyMainProject.app/MyMainProject (0x10139aaa0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

### Question

**Is there any way to condition the `Podfile` if the `framework` is already in `Package Manager` to not initialise it or to remove the `SDWebImage` from the `MainProject Package Dependencies`?**

**Or is posibile to use the `SDWebImage`, that is installed in my `MainProject` with pods, in my `Packet` that is installed with `Package Manager`?**

Comment: Remove `SDWebImage` from `podfile` and add with `SPM`

Comment: but if i add `SDWebImage` with `SPM`, can be used in `My Personal Package` with `import SDWebImage` and so?

Comment: Yes add with `SPM` where you need it. In yours case its project and library